# How to make owl-carousel fade effect to work with multiple images not for a single one(as said in documentation)

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have an Owl Carousel view, and I need to load 5 items per slide, but I want to use fade effect instead of slide. Fade effect is said to work only for single item per page slideshow.

Is it possible to make the fade effect work for multiple images in a row?

Comment: Did you see any option where you can set transitionStyle - then set it to "fade".

Comment: There's such field but it says: "Add CSS3 transition style. Works only with one item on screen."  I need to work with 5 items per screen :)

Comment: According to actual documentation it should work,  In the example you could see fade effect for each slide. just try [link]http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html

Comment: yea I can see effect for each slide, but the exampe is with ONE item. I need this effect to work with 5 items on ONE page, fading with another 5 items. You seem not to understand me...

Comment: @MladenMladenov, have you found a solution?